# Does Google App Engine support Java 8?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Trying to get started with Google App Engine - does it work with Java 8?

I've followed the instructions on this page:
https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine

Selecting 'Java', I successfully completed the Maven build, but when I visit localhost:8080 nothing is running.

The instructions say "make sure you have Java 7 JDK installed" however I have just installed Java 8 JDK.

Do I need to separately install Apache?

Comment: It now support Java8 (in BETA) https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8

Comment: Please see my answer below for the state of play as of today. You might like to change the accepted answer!

Comment: The accepted answer should get updated. Java 8 is available on all flavors of App Engine now.

Comment: Google App Engine Java 8 support is GA now. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**[The passage of time has changed the 'no' from this accepted answer to 'yes'. Please see others answers below.]**

Short answer, no.  They will integrate it over time, but for now if you use it, it will cause you a lot of errors. I would recommend against it

Also take note of user7610's answer below :). It is as of now the only way to have Java 8 on the Cloud Platform

Comment: Here's a fairly recent post of a Google employee which confirms that Java 8 is coming to GAE: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/8y80sEhr7Rc/66WnFoBvL3AJ

Comment: @JensBannmann Still not supported as it seems because I am still getting that "Unsupported .. version.." exception ..

Comment: @displayname look into Flex. I really think this will be the way to go to be able to run Java8. You can control whichever runtime you want with them :).

Comment: your question is popular and everyone looking for the problem related to google app engine and java 8 may confuse due to accepted answer. @Ian has answer which have the solution of problem.

Comment: Google App Engine Java 8 support is generally available as of Q3 2017. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8

Answer (score 14):

[Java 8 is now generally available on App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/06/Google-App-Engine-standard-now-supports-Java-8.html), joining the GA runtime on the App Engine Flexible Environment.

[Learn about the differences](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/).

The new Java 8 runtime has all the benefits of Java 7 but with upgrades and enhancements:

- OpenJDK 8-based Java runtime supports the standard public Java
  library (no whitelist)
- Doesn't impose a security manager--your code won't be restricted by Java permissions issues.

Answer (score 11):

Not at the time of writing but you can keep track of the status in this issue:

- Java 8 support: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9537

Answer (score 10):

Update: it is available in the "standard" (sandboxed) offering since mid 2017, https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/java-8-on-app-engine-standard-environment-is-now-generally-available

Before then, it was sort-of available, via Managed VMs. The idea is that you provide a Docker container with whatever software you need (like Java 8) and GAE will use that as your app instance VMs. You still get the autoscaling, monitoring and all that.

The disadvantage of Managed VMSs is that you are charged as for the Compute Engine VMs. That means you pay by minute and there is no free quota. There is the $300 credit for new user accounts for 60 days, but after that you'd have to pay.

Comment: How to map Docker Container with GAE Managed VMS??

Comment: Hey user7610. Just noticed a small error in your answer: the trial ks actually 60 days. Not 3 months.

Comment: Updated, thanks. Either I made a mistake in the first place, or the terms changed.

Answer (score 4):

If your interest is in using lambda expressions on Google App Engine, you could give [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) a try. I haven't tried it yet, but it claims to backport Java 8 lambda expressions to Java 7.

Answer (score 4):

Google App Engine Java 8 support is generally available as of Q3 2017. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite the same thing, but you can use Java 8 with the new App Engine "[flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/)". I don't think you can access App Engine APIs (such as the images service or task queues) but you'll be able to use services which live outside of App Engine, such as the Datastore and Pub/Sub.

It's also worth bearing in mind that the service is currently in beta (so not covered by any SLAs). Also, the [pricing is different](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing); instead of using the normal App Engine pricing structure, it's based on usage of GCE virtual machines.

Answer (score 2):

yes it does. We just launched this to Beta and soon GA.

https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/06/Google-App-Engine-standard-now-supports-Java-8.html

Answer (score 2):

App Engine Standard Java now supports Java8.
See the Beta documentation at: [Java8 on GAE Standard documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add `<runtime>java8</runtime>` to your appengine-web.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using App Engine flexible environment. Here are the official docs:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/

And here is the github repo for this implementation:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-vm-runtime

Answer (score 0):

You can apparently use JDK8 to create JRE7 compatible byte code, and this seems to be what Google recommends: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download

```
-source 1.7 -target 1.7
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, You can use flexible environment. and change setting of your `app.yaml`

```
vm: true
```

for more information study https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/