# Jetty IllegalArgumentException when using 1.9.30 GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jetty

I've been on a very old version of GAE for a long time. Every time I try to update to the latest version I get this error when deploying it to GCP:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is 
Java 7: org/eclipse/jetty/http/BadMessageException.class in C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXX\
backendservlet\build\exploded-app\WEB-
INF\lib\jetty-http-9.3.2.v20150730.jar
```

I think jetty comes with GAE so how do I fix this? When I deploy it locally it runs without errors. It also builds without error. This only happens when deploying to GCP.

My appengine instance is on JAVA 7 runtime so maybe that's the issue? How do I change that? I tried deplying with a different version and name and it still didn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like jetty (or at least the version you're using) needs Java 8, which is not supported on GAE: [Does Google App Engine support Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169557/does-google-app-engine-support-java-8).

Comment: I purged some unnecessary libraries and managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

GAE does not yet support Java 8. If jetty is a dependency of your project, you need to use a version that has source 1.7. Otherwise delete C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXX\
backendservlet\build\exploded-app\WEB-
INF\lib\jetty-http-9.3.2.v20150730.jar